# Direct link to VC++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable from custom installer

Tags: visual-c++, redistributable

I have installer that contains vcredist_x86.exe / vcredist_x64.exe so if user machine does not have VC++ redistributable installed then I install it.

However, the size of vcredist_x86.exe / vcredist_x64.exe is quite large ~5MB, which may be a problem for a small application.

Is there a direct (and permanent) link to Microsoft site that I could use instead of adding vcredist files to my installer?

Or may be there is even better way to solve such problem?

P.S. I am aware that user machine would have to be online - this is OK.

Comment: vcredist_x86 is VC++ Redistributable package, not Visual Studio! Do you understand the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328)
- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523)

Comment: Thank you, though I have a question: Are these links permanent, i.e. may I be sure they will not disappear/change in the future? I know, I know, that anything may happen :) but still, how could I proof to myself that these links can be included into real-world commercial application?

Comment: Sorry, these links lead to web-page while I was wondering about direct links to the packages...

Comment: @Alex: I think they are permanent, otherwise it would be a giant headache for Microsoft themselves to manage that. As backup you can provider a link to [search result](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=Visual+C%2b%2b+2010+Redistributable), but that's more definitely a subject to change.

Comment: @Alex: What bad in download page? Download link is definitely a subject to change, whenever web page url is not.

Comment: I was looking for something like http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/1/1116b75a-9ec3-481a-a3c8-1777b5381140/vcredist_x86.exe. This is for 2008 though and the same concerns apply.

Comment: I need a direct link to vcredist installers because this would allow me to download them from my installer. Having a link to a page that contains the required link somewhere is not that helpful, do you agree?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, I understand your concern. But download link can be changed in any day, up to MS infrastructure, many times during your app's life-cycle. So I'd recommend to do not download blindly but provide to user a download page where he could download manually, also be redirected what doubtfully easy to handle by code.

Comment: In other words you are saying there is no answer to the question? OK, I will accept your answer if no one else gives a better one within a week.

Comment: @Alex: You can grab the resulting download urls from these pages and see will they work for the time, or will break.

Comment: @romkyns: just tried, worked for me, please try again

Answer (score 8):

Here are the direct links for MSVC 2010 redists:

**MSVC 2010 SP1 Redist x86 English**
http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/6/D/C6D0FD4E-9E53-4897-9B91-836EBA2AACD3/vcredist_x86.exe

**MSVC 2010 SP1 Redist x64 English**
http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/8/0/A80747C3-41BD-45DF-B505-E9710D2744E0/vcredist_x64.exe

As you can see from those URLs, Microsoft is using UUIDs to index all their downloads, which looks like a good design decision and suggests that those links are indeed going to remain valid for a long time.

Comment: Did you determine these links by going to the regular download page, clicking download and then using the link from the "If your download does not start [...] Click here" link? I would like to be able to follow the same procedure you did to get these links.

Comment: @Jim yes, that's pretty much what I did. Using Firefox, I googled and downloaded the redistributable from Microsoft's website, then opened Firefox's download manager window (ctrl+J), right click, "copy download link"